# job queue implementation for python

Tags: python, job-queue

Do you know/use any distributed job queue for python? Can you share links or tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to multiprocessing there's also the [Celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/0.6.0) project, if you're using Django.

Comment: Thanks for the link? Is it strictly used with django? can we use it for standard python projects?

Comment: I don't see why not, with suitable adaptation (not sure how much work that'll be - depends on your exact requirement).

Comment: Celery has an underlying library, called Carrot, that you can use without Django.

Comment: Both Celery and Carrot works without Django. Or that is, you can use it from outside of a Django project. Recently someone even implemented paste support: http://bitbucket.org/twillis/celery-paste/

Comment: Celery is now *designed* to be used outside of Django (but still has Django support if you need it)

Answer (score 12):

Pyres is a resque clone built in python. Resque is used by Github as their message queue. Both use Redis as the queue backend and provide a web-based monitoring application.

http://binarydud.github.com/pyres/intro.html

Answer (score 3):

There's also "bucker" by Sylvain Hellegouarch which you can find here:

- http://trac.defuze.org/wiki/bucker

It describes itself like this:

- bucker is a queue system that supports multiple storage for the queue (memcached, Amazon SQS for now) and is driven by XML messages sent over a TCP connections between a client and the queue server.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [beanstalkd](http://xph.us/software/beanstalkd/)

Answer (score 2):

redqueue?
It's implemented in python+tornado framework, speaks memcached protocol and is optionally persistent into log files.
Currently it is also able to behave like beanstalkd, the reserve/delete way in memcache protocol as well.

[REDQUEUE](http://github.com/superisaac/redqueue)

Comment: At present, I have been using celery. I will look at the redqueue. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

If you think that Celery is too heavy for your needs then you might want to look at the simple distributed task queue:

- https://github.com/rojkov/taskqueue
- http://simpletaskqueue.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 1):

It's a year late or whatever, but this is something I've hacked together to make a queue of Processes executing them only X number at a time. http://github.com/goosemo/job_queue

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to look at multiprocessing's Queue. Included in Python 2.6, get it on PyPI for earlier versions of Python.

Standard library documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html
On PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing

Answer (score -3):

Also there is Unix 'at'

For more info:
man at