# How to maximize performance in Python when doing many I/O bound operations?

Tags: python

I have a situation where I'm downloading a lot of files. Right now everything runs on one main Python thread, and downloads as many as 3000 files every few minutes. The problem is that the time it takes to do this is too long. I realize Python has no true multi-threading, but is there a better way of doing this? I was thinking of launching multiple threads since the I/O bound operations should not require access to the global interpreter lock, but perhaps I misunderstand that concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could always take a look at [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Between Twisted and multiprocessing, which is going to provide the best performance advantage?

Comment: Twisted is most suited to networking specifically; multiprocessing is more straightforward if you're not used to the intricacies of asynch network programming.

Answer (score 16):

Multithreading is just fine for the specific purpose of speeding up I/O on the net (although asynchronous programming would give even greater performance).  CPython's multithreading is quite "true" (native OS threads) -- what you're probably thinking of is the GIL, the global interpreter lock that stops different threads from simultaneously running Python code.  But all the I/O primitives *give up the GIL* while they're waiting for system calls to complete, so the GIL is not relevant *to I/O performance*!

For asynchronous programming, the most powerful framework around is [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), but it can take a while to get the hang of it if you're never done such programming.  It would probably be simpler for you to get extra I/O performance via the use of a pool of threads.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a better way of doing this?

Yes

> I was thinking of launching multiple threads since the I/O bound operations

Don't.

At the OS level, all the threads in a process are sharing a limited set of I/O resources.

If you want real speed, spawn as many heavyweight OS processes as your platform will tolerate.  The OS is really, really good about balancing I/O workloads among processes.  Make the OS sort this out.

Folks will say that spawning 3000 processes is bad, and they're right.  You probably only want to spawn a few hundred at a time.

What you **really** want is the following.

1. A shared message queue in which the 3000 URI's are queued up.
2. A few hundred workers which are all reading from the queue.

   Each worker gets a URI from the queue and gets the file.

The workers can stay running.  When the queue's empty, they'll just sit there, waiting for work.

"every few minutes" you dump the 3000 URI's into the queue to make the workers start working.

This will tie up every resource on your processor, and it's quite trivial.  Each worker is only a few lines of code.  Loading the queue is a special "manager" that's just a few lines of code, also.

Comment: How are the workers (which are separate processes) able to share this global queue, which presumably sits in it's own process?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/ for example. http://www.darkcoding.net/software/choosing-a-message-queue-for-python-on-ubuntu-on-a-vps/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336489/job-queue-implementation-for-python

Answer (score 0):

[Gevent](http://gevent.org) is perfect for this.

Gevent's use of Greenlets (lightweight coroutines in the same python process) offer you asynchronous operations **without compromising code readability** or introducing abstract 'reactor' concepts into your mix.